# argument string containing dollar-sign

Tags: tfs

I have a PS-script that replaces a string in a configuration file (NLog config file).

The problem is that NLog uses dollar sign to indicate variables.. As do tfs.

Here is my argument I'm passing:

```
"\\myserver\logs\$(Release.ReleaseName)\issues\${shortdate}.log"
```

When I run my release, I get this line:

```
fileName="\\myserver\logs\20181017.17\issues\.log"
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue, I tried a few things but I also can't get it to work.

I succeed to pass the variable `${shortdate}` himself if I pass him with `' '`: `'${shortdate}'`.

As a workaround, you can pass 2 variables:

1) `'${shortdate}'`

2) `\\myserver\logs\$(Release.ReleaseName)\issues\_token_.log`

And replace the token in the PowerShell script:

```
Param(
 $variable,
 $string
)

 Write-Output $variable
 Write-Output $string
 $fullString = $string.Replace("_token_",$variable)
 Write-Output $fullString
```

It works for me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the workaround. But I will wait a day or two before accepting your answer too see if there is a more straight-forward approach.

Comment: I got it to work without the PS-replace part :D just a tfs-variable with the single-quotes. Thanks alot =D

Comment: Great :) Though I'm pretty sure I tried it and the build failed, so I thought about this solution... but I probably did not try well...